# WPF: Refresh ListView after adding item at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I have got a ListView which logs a process. The messages which are sent to log to the ListView should be shown after they were added. In my case the program stops for any user interaction and if the process is finished all items are visible.

But I need to see the item directly after adding and ever to be at the bottom of the list with the last added. Is there a possibility to refresh the ListView after adding of each item?

My XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvUpgrade">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="20px">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="75px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Time, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="300px" Header="Nachricht" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And the code behind:

```
Public Class Upgrade

    Public Sub AddMessage(ByVal message As Message)
        Me.lvUpgrade.Items.Add(message)
    End Sub

    Public Class Message

        Public Enum MessageType

            Normal
            Information
            Success
            Warning
            [Error]
        End Enum

        Public Sub New(ByVal type As MessageType, ByVal message As String)
            _Type = type
            _Message = message
        End Sub

        Private _Type As MessageType = MessageType.Normal
        Public ReadOnly Property Type As MessageType
            Get
                Return _Type
            End Get
        End Property

        Private _Message As String = String.Empty
        Public ReadOnly Property Message As String
            Get
                Return _Message
            End Get
        End Property

        Private _Time As DateTime = Now
        Public ReadOnly Property Time As DateTime
            Get
                Return _Time
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Icon As BitmapImage
            Get
                Select Case Me.Type
                    Case MessageType.Information
                        Return My.Resources.Information16.ToBitmapImage
                    Case MessageType.Success
                        Return My.Resources.OK16.ToBitmapImage
                    Case MessageType.Warning
                        Return My.Resources.Alert16.ToBitmapImage
                    Case MessageType.Error
                        Return My.Resources.Error16.ToBitmapImage
                    Case Else
                End Select

                Return Nothing
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Class
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: either use InotifyPropertyChange or DependecyProperties

Comment: Or ObservableCollection<T> which will fire a notify property changed event when the collection changes i.e. elements are added.